# How to find derivative of $y= \sin(x)^{\cos(x)-1}$??

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

$$y=(\sin(x))^{(\cos(x)-1)}$$

We multiply by $\ln$

$$\ln(y)=(\cos(x)-1)\cdot \ln(\sin(x))$$

$$\frac{y'}y=(\cos(x)-1)'\cdot  \ln(\sin(x)) + (\cos(x)-1)\cdot  \ln(\sin(x))'$$

$$\frac{y'}y=-\sin(x)\cdot \ln(\sin(x)) + (\cos(x)-1)\cdot \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

$$y'=y\cdot\bigg[(\cos(x)-1)\cdot \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} - (\sin(x))\cdot \ln(\sin(x))\bigg]$$

I am not sure if this is correct. If not help.

Comment: its correct, but side note , we're not multiplying by $\ln$, we're applying $\ln$ on both sides.

Comment: Also next time use Mathjax to format your question, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial on how to use mathjax